# Blob Trigger not working when published VS2017 .NET Core 2.0 Azure Function v2

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions

When I create a Azure Function with VS2017 in .NET Core 2.0, running locally, my blob trigger works fine. But when I publish to Azure, the trigger **does not fire** and no logs are written to the Azure Portal console.

My Function code.
[image]

My local.settings.json
[image]

After publishing, I go to the Azure portal and see this error: "The binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered.

[image]

I then attempt to install the **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage** but it fails. (I got here by trying to create a new trigger on the portal.)

[image]

If I keep trying, eventually it seems to install. But my published trigger doesn't respond to any file drops in my Blob Storage. The Function App's application setting, FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = beta and the run time is 2.x.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a breaking change for Azure Storage bindings for 2.x runtime:

*The Azure Storage bindings (blob, queues and tables triggers and bindings) were previously part of the runtime, but moving forward, will need to be explicitly installed. This change was made to allow Azure Functions to support multiple versions of the Azure Storage SDK*

*To temporarily avoid impact, you can pin your Function App to the previous version of the runtime by updating the app setting FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION to 2.0.11961-alpha*

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129